# How to exclude annotation encoding='Mathematica' from generated MathML?

Tags: export, conversion, xml

I do not see how to remove `<annotation encoding='Mathematica'` from generated MathML. Afaict it is not needed for a one way conversion and it often doubles the size of generated MathML.

How to do this quickly?

Shouldn't `"Annotations"->{}` option handle this?

```
(mathml = ExportString[Column@List@f[x], "MathML", "Annotations" -> {}]) // AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

```
0.0025588
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <semantics>
  ....
  <annotation encoding='Mathematica'>TagBox[...</annotation>  (*THIS is a waste of space for me*)
 </semantics>
</math>
```

I can mathml->XMLElement->DeleteCase->ExportString but then the procedure takes +500% of time for something that could've been just dropped before.

```
mathml // 
  ImportString[#, "XMLElement"] & // 
  DeleteCases[#, XMLElement["annotation", ___], \[Infinity]] & // 
  ExportString[#, "XML"] & // 
  AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

```
0.0108532
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <semantics>
  ...
 </semantics>
</math>
```

Comment: Back to working on M2MD?

Comment: @Szabolcs yes a little but this question originated completely independently. :)

Comment: There are the Presentation and Content options. Naively, I would have thought that this falls under "content" and therefore should not be generated at all with `"Content"->False` (the default). I might be mistaken. but this is definitely not something to be displayed ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Trace` reveals that `` XML`MathML`BoxesToSymbolicMathML `` is used under the hood and it has an `"IncludeMarkupAnnotations"` option which seems to do the job:

```
ExportString[Column@List@f[x], "MathML",  "IncludeMarkupAnnotations" -> False]
```

```
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <mtable>
  <mtr>
   <mtd>
    <mrow>
     <mi>f</mi>
     <mo>&#8289;</mo>
     <mo>(</mo>
     <mi>x</mi>
     <mo>)</mo>
    </mrow>
   </mtd>
  </mtr>
 </mtable>
</math>
```

Comment: This option is documented in `XML/tutorial/MathML`. (I find it by searching `IncludeMarkupAnnotations` in the document, strangely the page is not linked to `ref/format/MathML`. )

Comment: @xzczd thanks. {format}+F1 is my goto when I convert something so I expected it there.